# Patindex Extract Date with either M/D/YY or MM/DD/YY

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following code which extracts the date from a string and saves it to a temp table:

I need the patindex to be flexible to extract 2 digit day and 2 digit month as well. The example below has just one digit month.

```
DECLARE @Stringval VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @Dateval DATETIME;

 DECLARE @DATETIME_TBL TABLE
 (
    datetime_val DATETIME 
 )


SET @Stringval = 'Cairo Egypt - 1-15-10 System 1..' 

IF ISDATE(SUBSTRING(@Stringval, patindex('%[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]%', @Stringval), 8)) = 1
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO @DATETIME_TBL
  VALUES (CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(@Stringval, patindex('%[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]%', @Stringval), 8)))
END

Select * from @DateTIME_TBL
```

I understand that for 1-15-10, it may need just one [0-9] but anyway we can have it flexible to include 2 digit month and 2 digit day all in one patindex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some code that works in both cases.  It makes me nervous to combine both conditions into 1 insert statement.  Imo it's more self-documenting and reliable (logic-wise) to make 2 insert statements (but only run both if necessary by checking @@rowcount after the first attempted insert).

Variables and temp tables

```
declare @stringval varchar(500)='Cairo Egypt - 1-15-10 System 1..';

declare @stringval_tbl table(
    string_val  varchar(500));

insert @stringval_tbl select @stringval;

declare @datetime_tbl table (
    datetime_val datetime);
```

Insert statement

```
insert @datetime_tbl
select convert(datetime, substring(st.string_val, ndx.loc+1, 7))
from @Stringval_tbl st
      cross apply
      (select patindex('% [0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]%', @Stringval) loc) ndx
where ndx.loc>0
      and isdate(substring(st.string_val, ndx.loc, 7))=1;
if @@rowcount=0
    insert @DATETIME_TBL
    select convert(datetime, substring(st.string_val, ndx.loc, 8))
    from @Stringval_tbl st
          cross apply
          (select patindex('%[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]%', @Stringval) loc) ndx
    where ndx.loc>0
          and isdate(substring(st.string_val, ndx.loc, 8))=1;
```

Output (when @stringval='Cairo Egypt - 1-15-10 System 1..')

```
datetime_val
2010-01-15 00:00:00.000
```

Output (when @stringval='Cairo Egypt - 11-15-10 System 1..')

```
datetime_val
2010-11-15 00:00:00.000
```